# kendo multiselect setting default values

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a problem with setting default values of kendo `multiselect`. On the site I've been developing, I'm trying to keep selected values on `multiselect`. When someone select a value(s), I send the values to database. When the user refresh the site, I want to get value from db and set multiselect's default values(I mean values will be on multiselect's input.) I did it with this way :

```
$(function () {
    $.get('Home/GetAppsJson/', function (data) {
        if (data[0] != null) {  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i] == null)
                    break;
                $('<li class="k-button" unselectable="on"></li>').appendTo('.k-multiselect-wrap ul');
                $('<span></span>', {
                    text: data[i],
                    unselectable: "on"
                }).appendTo($('.k-multiselect-wrap ul li.k-button').eq(i));
            }
            $('<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-delete">delete</span>').appendTo('.k-multiselect-wrap ul li.k-button');
        }
    });
});
```

but this time when I remove the value from `multiselect`, `onChange` event doesn't work. It seems `multiselect` can't detect the values on input. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved problem by using "value()" function.

```
 $.get('Home/GetAppsJson/', function (data) {
        var values = new Array();
        if (data[0] != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i] == null)
                    break;
                values[i]=data[i];
            }
        }
        var multiselect = $('#applications').data("kendoMultiSelect");
        multiselect.value(values);
    });
```